Assembling expression for a filters on a referenced table
I am writing a search/report generator and need to write where clauses based on user input. When the filtering value is for a field, it is all fine. Also I can filter on a child table when reference is many-to-one. However, I have problems composing a clause where I need to query a child table referenced by the main table with one-to-many relationship.
I created a simplified code to address this specific issue:
I used an MVC API template and injected SQL server database like
var sqlConnectionString = "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb;Database=TestEntity;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true";
services.AddDbContext<DataContext>((serviceProvider, options) =>
                                                   {
                                                       options.UseSqlServer(sqlConnectionString);
                                                   });

The context was defined like
public class DataContext : DbContext
{
    public DataContext(DbContextOptions<DataContext> options) : base(options) { }
    protected DataContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options) { }

    public DbSet<Car> Cars { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Colour> Colour { get; set; }
}

public class Colour
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public Car[] Cars { get; set; }
}

public class Car
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public string Make { get; set; }
    public string Model { get; set; }
    public int StartProductionYear { get; set; }

    public Guid ColourId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(ColourId))]
    public Colour Colour { get; set; }
}

And the calling methods were defined like this:
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class SearchController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly DataContext _context;

    public SearchController(DataContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    [HttpGet("[action]")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetColourByCar([FromQuery] string make) // does not work
    {
        // define the field that will allow to reuse the logic for different fields
        Expression<Func<Car, string>> modelInside = c => c.Make;

        // compose the expression to use in the inner Where clause
        Expression<Func<Car, bool>> byMake = modelInside.Compose(v => v.Equals(make));

        // compose the expression to be used in the outer Where clause
        // this is where I fail to proceed as Where (or Any) expects a Func here, not Expression, and I cannot set one that would be accepted by the entity framework
        Expression<Func<Colour, bool>> exp = c => c.Cars.Where(byMake);
        var carsColor = await _context.Colour
            .Where(exp)
            .ToListAsync();

        return Ok(carsColor);
    }

    [HttpGet("[action]")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetCarByColour([FromQuery] string colour) // works OK
    {
        Expression<Func<Colour, string>> colourInside = c => c.Name; 
        Expression<Func<Colour, bool>> byColour = colourInside.Compose(v => v.Equals(colour));

        Expression<Func<Car, Colour>> outside = c => c.Colour;
        Expression<Func<Car, bool>> exp = outside.Compose(byColour);
        var carsColor = await _context.Cars
            .Where(exp)
            .ToListAsync();

        return Ok(carsColor);
    }
}

for Compose I used code from How can I include one expression in another expression? :
    public static Expression<Func<TSource, TResult>> Compose<TSource, TIntermediate, TResult>(
        this Expression<Func<TSource, TIntermediate>> first,
        Expression<Func<TIntermediate, TResult>> second)
    {
        var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TSource));
        var intermediateValue = first.Body.ReplaceParameter(first.Parameters[0], param);
        var body = second.Body.ReplaceParameter(second.Parameters[0], intermediateValue);
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<TSource, TResult>>(body, param);
    }

    private static Expression ReplaceParameter(this Expression expression, ParameterExpression toReplace, Expression newExpression)
        => new ParameterReplaceVisitor(toReplace, newExpression).Visit(expression);

    private class ParameterReplaceVisitor(ParameterExpression from, Expression to) : ExpressionVisitor
    {
        protected override Expression VisitParameter(ParameterExpression node) => node == from ? to : node;
    }

How can I pass Expression to a child collection?
More broadly - am I approaching the user reports data generator correctly, or are there better ways - like a library or a well-known pattern?
Edited:
I need it to write filter methods that can be reused by passing different fields. I need it to generate custom data sets based on user-configurable filters. I provide users with a list of supported columns, and in the application, I have a different logic based on the user input.
An example user flow for the tables I specified would be:
In the UI a user selects

Colour equals Yellow
Make contains Rover
Year of manufacturing higher or equal than 1990

and in the end, the database will have a (parametrised) query like
select t.* from Colour t
inner join Cars t0 on t.id = t0.ColourId
where t.Name = 'yellow' and t0.Make like '%rover%' and t0.StartProductionYear >= 1990

I want to write a method that will accept a condition type and return an EF-compatible expression that I will use to query a db set.
So I will have a set of methods that will have different sets of conditions inside depending on the selected field type.
This is what I have for a string
private Expression<Func<Colour, bool>> AssembleString(Expression<Func<Colour, string>> fieldExpression, Condition condition, string value)
{
    Expression<Func<Colour, bool>> e = condition
    switch
    {
        ColumnCondition.Equal => fieldExpression.Compose(v => v.Equals(value)),
        ColumnCondition.NotEqual => fieldExpression.Compose(v => !v.Equals(value)),
        ColumnCondition.Bigger => fieldExpression.Compose(v => v.Compare(value) > 0),
        ColumnCondition.Less => fieldExpression.Compose(v => v.Compare(value) < 0),
        ColumnCondition.Contain => fieldExpression.Compose(v => v.Contains(value)),
        ColumnCondition.BeginWith => fieldExpression.Compose(v => v.StartsWith(value)),
        ColumnCondition.EndWith => fieldExpression.Compose(v => v.EndsWith(value)),
        ColumnCondition.Blank => fieldExpression.Compose(v => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(v)),
        ColumnCondition.NotBlank => fieldExpression.Compose(v => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(v)),
        _ => _ => false
    };

    return e;
}

I specified the Colour type there, but I will make it generic after I make the logic work.
I will also use free text search indexes for some columns, but it is out of the scope of the question.
I need a similar method that will work for a referenced field where the relationship is one-to-many (the field of the child type is a collection)

I know several ways, easiest via LINQKit and it's Expand() extension method. It is hard to advise something better without understanding why this is needed.

@SvyatoslavDanyliv edited the question with an example

@SvyatoslavDanyliv I will check the suggested LINQKit tomorrow, but from reading the description it might be what I need. Thank you!

Check this my answer, looks like it is what you are trying to build.
